# Import XML data with into SQL Server with Romanian charset

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

I have a problem encoding a XML file from Romania. The file is in utf-8 and has the following content (only an excerpt)

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding "utf-8"?>
<EXPORT>
     <ORDER>
         <ID> 91420 </ID>
         <CUSTOMER>
             <STREET> Str Primcipală nr 211 comuna Şuncuiuş </STREET>
         </CUSTOMER>
         <CURRENCY> RON </CURRENCY>
    </ORDER>
</EXPORT>
```

I read the file into SQL Server like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Xml (Data) 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '... \ order-91420.xml', CodePage = 'RAW', SINGLE_BLOB) as Data;
```

As a result, I get the following

```
Str Primcipala nr 211 comuna? Uncuiu ?, loc. Balnac
```

How can I read the file with correct characters, specifically `"Şuncuiuş"`

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is the **datatype** of your `#Xml.Data` column? SQL Server 2008 R2 doesn't support UTF-8 by default

Comment: If your file is real `utf-8`, this might get difficult. The fact, that the XML's header states this encoding, is not necessarily the truth. SQL-Server introduced native BULK import for `utf-8` with v14SP1 (afaic). Try to find out the real encoding of your XML.

Comment: I just looked it up. UTF-8 import was [introduced with SQL-Server 2014 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq)